# Sencha Touch MVC: How do I access data in a view?

Tags: sencha-touch

New to Sencha Touch, floundering in the dark. In my controller, I define a a variable inside an action thus:

```
this.map = this.render({
    xtype: 'contact-map',
    data: this.person.data,
    listeners: {
        deactivate: function(map) {
            map.destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

My question is, how do I access the `data` element (`this.person.data`) from the view `'contact-map'`? I know how to via a template `tpl` element like `<p>{foo}</p>`, but how would I do so in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data becomes a property on the view object you create.

So in your initComponent method you can reference it using the this pointer, i.e. this.data.

Event handlers for the view usually pass the view in as the first argument to the callback so you'd access it with that.  In your deactivate handler you'd use map.data.

Comment: thanks for the info. So, if I had items on the data, say foo and bar, would I access them in the view via this.data.get('foo')?

Comment: @Buffalo if it's an Ext.Model yes.  Otherwise just data.foo or data.bar.